# Main class in SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my first day with SpringBoot, I try to understand the architecture so I started building a hello world application:

In my pom.xml, under maven-shade-plugin I state mainClass as follows:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <mainClass>com.demo.HelloWorld</mainClass>
</transformer>
```

And here's the **groupId** and **artifactId** values of the pom file:

```
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
```

When I package with maven (**mvn package**) and run the war file (target/demo.war), I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.demo.HelloWorld
```

The file destination is **src/main/java/com/demo/HelloWorld.java**, and the code in that file is:

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class, args);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to start your project from the one generated with https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to understand architecture deeply, so I try to build manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use spring-boot maven plugin -> [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html), it makes executable jar without any configuration.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. Does it mean that my approach is right - except the part I package?

Comment: With creating **Hello World** class, yes.